# Как создать классы из большого API автоматически в C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть API телеграмма https://core.telegram.org/bots/api и там есть вкладка "*Available types*"
Нужно достать все типы в формате:

```cs
public class User
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public bool is_bot { get; set; }
    public string? first_name { get; set; }
    public string? last_name { get; set; }
    public string? username { get; set; }
    public string? language_code { get; set; }
    public bool is_premium { get; set; }
    public bool added_to_attachment_menu { get; set; }
    public bool can_join_groups { get; set; }
    public bool can_read_all_group_messages { get; set; }
    public bool supports_inline_queries { get; set; }
}
```

**Как это сделать автоматически или намного быстрее (типов там очень много)**

Comment: [Вставка JSON или XML в качестве классов](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/reference/paste-json-xml?view=vs-2022) / [Сайт 1](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp) / [Сайт 2](https://json2csharp.com). Но ИМХО, советую руками, ибо 1. Не всегда нужны все свойства (а если нужны, то зачем руками писать это все, если есть уже готовые библиотеки?). 2. Не всегда эти "конверторы" определяют правильно структуру, тип, имя (например у вас в вопросе класс с нарушением именования, ибо публичное свойство должно быть написано слитно, без пробелов и символов, каждое слово с заглав. будквы.)